# CSS basic float layout, margin-top for footer

Tags: html, css, layout, margins

I am trying to get a basic layout going with CSS.

Header
Aside - Content
Footer

I put a margin-top property for the footer, but i am not sure why it is not working. Here is the simple code I have so far:

```css
 

<style>

header {
 width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
 border: 1px solid black;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}

aside {
 width: 100px;
 height: 200px;
 border: 1px solid green;
 float: left;
 margin-right:10px;
}

article {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    float: left;
}

footer {
 clear: both;
 border: 1px solid blue;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100px;
 margin-top: 10px;
}

</style>
```

```html
<header> &nbsp; </header>
<aside>&nbsp;</aside>    
<article>&nbsp;</article>    
<footer>&nbsp;</footer>
```

You can see the footer not getting a margin here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAHQf.png

Comment: try `margin-bottom:10px;` in article as https://jsfiddle.net/w735wunw/ which is just a work around

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add display: inline-block; in footer.

```css
<style>

header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

aside {
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    float: left;
    margin-right:10px;
}

article {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    float: left;
}

footer {
    clear: both;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: 10px;
 display: inline-block;
}

</style>
```

```html
<header>
    </header>

    <aside>
    </aside>

    <article>
    </article>

    <footer>
    </footer>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! How would I get article to take up the remainder space instead of just 200px?

Comment: Replace  width:200px to  width: calc(100% - 113px);

Answer (score 1):

Try It Once

```css
*{
margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}
header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom:10px;
    
}

aside {
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    float: left;
   margin-bottom:10px;
   
}

article {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    float: left;
   margin-bottom:10px;
   
}

footer {
    clear: both;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
   margin-right:10px;
    
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
    </header>

    <aside>
    </aside>

    <article>
    </article>

    <footer>
    </footer>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

---

```
body{
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;


}

header{
    border-radius:10px;


    padding:10px 1%;
    margin:10px 1%;
    background-color:#066;
    text-align:center;
}


article{
    background-color:#066;
    width:50%;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    border-radius:10px;
    text-align:center;
    margin:10px;

}

content{
     background-color:#066;
     width:40%;
     height:100%;
     border-radius:10px;
     text-align:center;
     margin:10px;
     float:right;
}
footer{

    clear:both;
    border-radius:10px;
    background-color:#066;
    text-align:center;
    padding:10px;
    margin:10px; 
}
```

---

```
       <header>
            <h2>Header</h2>
              </header>
                <article>
                 <h2>Aside</h2>
                   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.       Maecenas id odio velit. Praesent orci lectus, fermentum vel ullamcorper vel, pharetra ac elit. Fusce eu sapien ac ligula tempor fermentum. Sed vulputate rutrum mattis. Ut et metus ac lectus fermentum porttitor.</p>
                    </article>  
                      <content>
                       <h2>Content</h2>
                       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas id odio velit. Praesent orci lectus, fermentum vel ullamcorper vel, pharetra ac elit. Fusce eu sapien ac ligula tempor fermentum. Sed vulputate rutrum mattis. Ut et metus ac lectus fermentum porttitor. </p>
                   </content>
                 <footer>
              <h2>Footer</h2>
        </footer>
```